# Ruby Sass Deprecation - How Do I see If my Version is Being Deprecated

Tags: ruby, sass, dart, deprecated

I've seen on a few blogs and Twitter recently that Ruby Sass is being deprecated.  When you look on the Sass docs, the installation method they use is the one I've always used on the command line i.e. `gem install sass` -- is this being made redundant? And if it is how do i install the new Dart Sass I've seen mentioned?

When I do `sass --version` it shows `sass 3.5.5 (Bleeding Edge)` which doesn't sound like something that is about to be deprecated?

V confused.

Comment: didn't know about this before, but it looks like there's a little guide [in their blog post](http://sass.logdown.com/posts/7081811) ... have you tried that?

Answer (score 0):

You've got the Ruby version. Dart version should be numbered (at least at time of writing):

```
1.3.x
e.g.,
1.3.2
```

How to install the dart version depends on which operating system you have and the link already provided gives these instructions. I use MacOS Sierra and ran in to a couple of problems. For anyone using Mac the things listed below may be helpful:

1. Before installation change permissions on /usr/local:

   - sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local 
     NOTE: don't forget to change permissions back when done:
   - sudo chown root:wheel /usr/local
2. Makes sure homebrew is healthy and updated before installing anything new:

   - brew update
   - brew cleanup
   - brew doctor